# Not able to deploy VB6 based setup on Windows 7

Tags: vb6, windows-7, installation, legacy, ocx

I have a setup created using Vb6. I am unable to install it under Windows 7. Windows 7 is not registering OCX controls included in the setup.

Same setup works fine under Windows XP and all other previous Microsoft operating systems.

Windows 7 OS is 64 bit.

Also, I have tried all compatibility mode which is available under Windows 7 without much luck.

Unfortunately I don't have source code with me. Otherwise I could have ported entire source to Dot Net.

Comment: Your best bet might be to run XP 32 bit (or even Win 2k) under a Virtual Machine and install VS 6 on the VM.